# System log error

Tags: xml, magento, module, product, mage

I followed this tutorial, from this site: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/
I have to mentioned that I have the same code as in the site. The problem is when I create/update o product I got in var/log/system.log this error:

```
"2013-12-02T08:36:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\magento\includes\src\Mage_Smashingmagazine_Logproductupdate_Model_Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\magento\includes\src\Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2013-12-02T08:36:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\magento\includes\src\Mage_Smashingmagazine_Logproductupdate_Model_Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\magento\includes\src;.;C:\xampp\php\pear\;D:\xampp\php\zend1\library')  in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\magento\includes\src\Varien_Autoload.php on line 93"
```

Can anyone tell me why??? The compilation is disabled and I clear the chache frequently.
Thx in advance
/***************************************************************************/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
                          <class>smashingmagazine_logproductupdate/observer</class>
                          <method>logUpdate</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </smashingmagazine_logproductupdate >
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

/********************************************************************************/

This is the observer

```
<?php
/**
 * Our class name should follow the directory structure of
 * our Observer.php model, starting from the namespace,
 * replacing directory separators with underscores.
 * i.e. app/code/local/SmashingMagazine/
 *                     LogProductUpdate/Model/Observer.php
 */
class SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    /**
     * Magento passes a Varien_Event_Observer object as
     * the first parameter of dispatched events.
     */
    public function logUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        // Retrieve the product being updated from the event observer
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        // Write a new line to var/log/product-updates.log
        $name = $product->getName();
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        Mage::log(
            "{$name} ({$sku}) updated",
            null, 
            'product-updates.log',
            true
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the compilation is disabled? This looks like a compilation enabled error.

Comment: Im pretty sure about it

Comment: if i include in .htaccess this line "SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1" of the bottom of file, it throw me instead of system .log  an exception.log with the content: "013-12-02T09:22:38+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: include(Mage\Smashingmagazine\Logproductupdate\Model\Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\magento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php:245
Stack trace:"

Comment: Most probably the `config.xml` file of the module is not correct. You might want to add that to the question. I think it's missing a model alias.

Comment: ok. but what have i have to change on config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some point need to take care while creating config xml in Magento.

1. Always use `<Namesapce_Modulename>` not `<NameSpace_ModuleName>` as it will not work when you create object using `'namesapce/modulename'` as Magento try to find the class like `Namespace_Modulename_Model_Class` not `NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Class`.
2. In your case either change your Namespace and Moduel name properly or use the below config.xml

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Smashingmagazine_Logproductupdate>
               <version>0.0.1</version>
           </Smashingmagazine_Logproductupdate>
       </modules>
       <global>
           <events>
               <catalog_product_save_after>
                   <observers>
                       <smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
                             <class>smashingmagazine_logproductupdate/observer</class>
                             <method>logUpdate</method>
                           <type>singleton</type>
                       </smashingmagazine_logproductupdate >
                   </observers>
               </catalog_product_save_after>
           </events>
       </global>
   </config>`
3. and change the folder name accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your config.xml inside the `<global>` tag

```
<models>
    <smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
        <class>SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate_Model</class>
    </smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
</models>
```

and clear the cache